# Inserting new data in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have created a basic table for learning purposes.

```
CREATE TABLE friends (
  id INT,
  name TEXT,
  birthday DATE
);
```

Added some data...

```
INSERT INTO friends (id,name,birthday)
VALUES (1,'Jo Monro','1948-05-30');

INSERT INTO friends (id,name,birthday)
VALUES (2, 'Lara Johnson','1970-03-03');

INSERT INTO friends (id,name,birthday)
VALUES (3,'Bob Parker', '1962-09-3');
```

And I realised that I forgot to include the email column.
I added the column...

```
ALTER TABLE friends
ADD COLUMN email;
```

..but how can I add now data to this new column only?

I have tried WHERE statements, rewriting the INSERT INTO statements with and without the other column names but nothing worked?

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Is UPDATE not an option? `UPDATE friends SET email = 'Jo.Monro@gmail.com' WHERE id = 1`

Comment: create Another table map_user_email with id and email of the corresponding person
And then use update query to update friends from  map_user_email
Set email


use 

`update friends f, map_user_email m
set f.email = m.mail
Where f.id = m.id`

Answer (score 2):

Insert the emails into a temporary table, then update the real table with that.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE friends (
>   id INT auto_increment primary key,
>   name VARCHAR(100),
>   birthday DATE
> );
>
> INSERT INTO friends (name, birthday) VALUES 
>   ('Jo Monro','1948-05-30')
> , ('Lara Johnson','1970-03-03')
> , ('Bob Parker', '1962-09-3');
>
> ALTER TABLE friends ADD COLUMN email VARCHAR(100);
>
> select * from friends
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name         | birthday   | email
> -: | :----------- | :--------- | :----
>  1 | Jo Monro     | 1948-05-30 | null 
>  2 | Lara Johnson | 1970-03-03 | null 
>  3 | Bob Parker   | 1962-09-03 | null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- temporary table for the emails
> --
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpEmails (
>  name varchar(100) primary key,
>  email varchar(100)
> );
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- fill the temp
> --
> insert into tmpEmails (name, email) values
>   ('Jo Monro','jo.monro@unmail.net')
> , ('Lara Johnson','lara.johnson@unmail.net')
> , ('Bob Parker', 'UltimateLordOfDarkness@chuni.byo');
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- update the real table
> --
> update friends friend
> join tmpEmails tmp
>   on friend.name = tmp.name
> set friend.email = tmp.email
> where friend.email is null;
> ```

> ```
> select * from friends
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name         | birthday   | email                           
> -: | :----------- | :--------- | :-------------------------------
>  1 | Jo Monro     | 1948-05-30 | jo.monro@unmail.net             
>  2 | Lara Johnson | 1970-03-03 | lara.johnson@unmail.net         
>  3 | Bob Parker   | 1962-09-03 | UltimateLordOfDarkness@chuni.byo
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=50f3e55fe8992241c2a40ffa266b0a5b)*